# Laravel upload to AWS EB migration:No migrations

Tags: laravel, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm looking for some help with Laravel. I have run `php artisan migrate:fresh` But only the migrations table is created and gives me the No Migrations message. I have a number of migration files in Database/migrations. Any ideas what has gone wrong? This is all working fine in mt WAMP environment. I am trying to upload it to an AWS EB instance

- I have downloaded the code as a zip from the remote repository.
- unzipped
- run `composer instal`
- edited the .env and database config
- and created the .ebextensions folder with init.config file containing:

`container_commands:
  01-initkey:
    command: "php artisan key:generate"
  02-migration:
        command: "php artisan migrate"
        leader_only: true`

The commands seem to run ok but can not find the migration files.

UPDATE

I have followed this video on how to upload to [AWS BS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ISVaMijczKc&t=1220s&pbjreload=10)

Still no luck. It looks like that when The migrate command is acted AWS can not find the migration folder.

I have also tried zipping the files from my WAMP server (where it works fine) Still only the migrations table is created.

Comment: Could you please post the full path from the project's root to your migrations directory?

Comment: can you share php artisan migrate: fresh command result? and inside of your migrations directory if not private.

Comment: `php artisan migrate:fresh --verbose` to see more output.

Comment: Path = Database/migrations, I have 10 files in this folder including the default user and password migrations. Command result = Completed activity. Result: Nothing to migrate. I have tried `php artisan migrate:fresh --verbose` This did not give me any more info. It looks like something is missing like the path to the migrations in the migration class? but I have not found where that would be yet.

Answer (score 0):

Forcing Migrations To Run In Production:

php artisan migrate --force

[Link documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations)

Comment: Hi Petrisor. Sorry but this has returned the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround. NOTE This has not fixed the problem it's just a workaround. I would still like to find a solution.

1. I changed my .env file with the aws with my rds details.
2. Then run PHP artisan migrate:fresh
3. I also deleted the .ebextensions folder before uploading the code.

As I said this has worked however this is a workaround and I would like to find a way to automate this with .ebextensions.